# Unity UI определить что пользователь кликнул не по сцене а по UI

Tags: c#, unity3d, gui

Ситуация может напоминать неправильный подход, но не спешите с выводами.
Есть обычный интерфейс, который обрабатывается целиком и полностью через стандартный EventSystem, на канвасе есть полноценный GraphicRaycaster. Кнопки жмутся, всё замечательно.

Далее, для игровой механики мне нужно ловить клики чтобы по ним делать рейкасты, тут начинается самое сложное. Есть Update метод:

```
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        Debug.Log("Механика!");
    }
}
```

Собственно, так же, надо помнить, что кроме окна сцены, игрок может нажать на кнопки. Если пользователь жмёт в окно сцены происходит ожидаемый текст в логе "Механика!". Далее если нажать на кнопку, происходит одно из двух:

1. Кнопка нижимается, выполняется событие кнопки, далее в консоль описывается "Механики!".
2. В консоль отписывается "Механики!", кнопка не нажимается.

Получается некий конфликт, мы воруем нажатия у UI. Собственно картина на Windows совершенно прозрачная, там есть курсор, он ведёт себя предсказуемо, если кликаем на кнопку, клик по сцене не проходит, выполняется событие кнопки, всё как я хочу. Если же эту сцену выполнять на андроид устройстве, происходит один из двух сценариев, описанных выше.

Вопрос к тем кто может подсказать как правильно вообще решать эту проблему: в UI есть EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() - который позволяет отфильтровывать, например, нажатия вне текущего элемента, что довольно удобно. Есть ли инструменты позволяющие:

1. Выполнять собственноручно остановку пропагации передачи клика следующим слоям.
2. Выполнять определение - кликая по сцене, попали ли мы на UI элемент, или клик был в обход всех Raycast Target объектов UI.

Если ручных механизмов нет, есть ли альтернативный вариант разделения реализации ведения кликов по UI элементам и по сцене, чтобы они не конфликтовали друг с другом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретно свою проблему удалось решить путём отказа от Update-логики для перехвата событий нажатий и кликов.

Что было сделано:

- На канвасе добавил новый GameObject, назвал его SceneView, формат RectTransform настроил так, чтобы он растягивался во весь экран. На объекте должен быть компонент который является Raycast Target (галочка должа быть включена), это может быть, например, прозрачный Image, или свой вариант UI объекта, не выполняющий отрисовку, но принимающий рейкасты от UI.
- Далее сцена стартует так, чтобы мой SceneView был всегда самым первый в иерархии внутри канваса (то-есть на слоях он будет самый последний)
- На этот SceneView я добавляю все необходимые скрипты для обработки нажатий, движений и прочих действий с нажатиями
- В скриптах использую исключительно интерфейсы UI событий: IPointerClickHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IDragHandler и т.д.

Таким образом, работает всегда только UI логика, и проблема конфликтов пропала. Кнопки жмутся, клик не доходит до слоёв ниже.